# TextView not displaying. Why?

Tags: android, textview

So this is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/fullimage" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/product_picture">
</ImageView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/custom_fullimage_placename"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code that populates the pic and the text :

```
AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog,
            null); //(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root)

    System.out.println(text);
    TextView picText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.custom_fullimage_placename);
    picText.setText(text);

    AQuery aq = new AQuery(layout);
    Bitmap placeholder = aq.getCachedImage(R.drawable.image_missing);
    aq.id(R.id.fullimage).image(imageUrl, true, true, 0, R.drawable.image_missing, placeholder, AQuery.FADE_IN_NETWORK, 0);

   ....
```

The image is displayed just fine, however i can't make the text appear..and I don't know why.

Any ideas?

EDIT :

I solved the problem thanks guys...I gave fixed limits to the image (set the width and height to 300dp..) Maybe it only works this way because it is inside an alert dialog...

Comment: your background is black color? change the text color and see. a guess.

Comment: its text color..and i put i red and still nothing

Comment: remove the android:layout_weight="1" in your textview

Comment: I do not see where you are setting the string "text" can you include that code?  If you have a string defined empty all you will get is a empty string.

Comment: @Ashwini Bhangi done it..still the same result

Comment: @Mark `System.out.println(text);` prints the correct string

Comment: Ok include the code for the string text...

Comment: Could be a threading issue, you may try moving the .setText to after the image getting loaded.

Comment: try removing image and check the text shows. if it does, something might be wrong on layout setting

Comment: if i remove the image code...it works :|  but what could the problem be?

Comment: what size is the image ?

Comment: Try setting the text after the image code.

Comment: @MarkBasler tried that..same results..It looks like it only works if I delete the pic code :(

Comment: Then at that point You have a problem with the layout.xml so you will need to look at adjust the size's on the layout of the image.

Comment: Also I would switch to using dp versus px on your layout for the size.

Comment: Try setting the max size for the imageview. also after setting the image, call linearlayout.invalidate() to refresh the linearlayout

Comment: I solved the problem thanks guys...I gave fixed limits to the image (like set the width and height to 300dp..) Maybe it only works this way because it is inside an alert dialog...

Comment: Ok then go ahead and post an answer and accept it then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you actually set the text value. Does the 'println' output show the expected value?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your textview color, which is actually black, just a guess

Comment: changed to red..still nothing

Comment: why the view comes from R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog, not from R.layout.layout_root? have you tested it?

Comment: i tried switching...but then i get a more complex failure...as the code is now, at least i have something